# Javascript, how redirect the main page if you use window.open?

Tags: javascript, http, popup, window.open, window.location

So I want open a new window/tab and use

```
<script>
    function popunder() {
        window.open("https://link.here", '_blank', 'toolbar=yes, location=yes, status=yes, menubar=yes, scrollbars=yes').blur();
    }
</script>
```

and it works, but I want forward the main page to a new website link at the same time when "window.open" open...

I use `onclick="popunder()"` too.

I have tried

`window.location.href` and `window.location.replace` but it doesn't work.

Also I have no experience of code at all.

How can I forward the main page to another link with the same click which calls window.open?

Comment: basically the same code, but remove '_blank' and replace with '_self'

Comment: Did you try doing this on a regular `<a>` link?

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to use `window.open` the magic lies in the second parameter (the window name that should be affected) You can read more here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

```js
window.open("http://google.com", "_blank");
// the above opens a new window/tab

window.open("http://bing.com", "_self");
// the above navigates to a new page.
```

**Note** on StackOverflow the google popup won't register because it's coming from within the sandbox. You can see a demonstrable version of the above code in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8cur47mq/) (*be sure not to have your popup blocker on*)